# Morphisms of adjunctions

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors

In [Mac Lane](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/maclanecat.pdf) a morphism of adjunctions $$(F\dashv G:\mathcal{C}\leftrightarrows\mathcal{D},\eta:1_\mathcal{C}\Rightarrow G\circ F,\epsilon:F\circ G\Rightarrow1_\mathcal{D})$$ $$\longrightarrow$$ $$(F'\dashv G':\mathcal{C}'\leftrightarrows\mathcal{D}',\eta':1_{\mathcal{C}'}\Rightarrow G'\circ F',\epsilon':F'\circ G'\Rightarrow1_{\mathcal{D}'})$$ is defined (p. 99) to consist of a pair of functors $$A:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}',\ B:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D}'$$ such that both obvious squares commute, so $B\circ F=F'\circ A$ and $A\circ G=G'\circ A$, together with a coherence condition on the induced maps between hom-sets.

There is a more general definition available, given by instead considering functors $A$ and $B$ as above together with natural transformations $$\alpha:B\circ F\Rightarrow F'\circ A,$$ $$\beta:A\circ G\Rightarrow G'\circ B,$$ such that the following diagrams commute [image]

This version has certainly been written up somewhere, but the nlab appears to have little to say on the subject; the first theorem following Mac Lane's definition in CWM is that $1\star\eta=\eta'\star1$ and $1\star\epsilon=\epsilon'\star1$ which follows trivially from this one if we take $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be identity natural transformations so it looks like we're good, but I'd be interested to read more about the lax version of this notion at the $1$-categorical level.

> Is there a reference available on this 'lax' notion of morphism between adjunctions written at the $1$-categorical level?

This is related to the 'lax' definition of a morphism of monads $$(T:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C},\eta,\mu)\rightarrow(T':\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D},\eta',\mu')$$ as a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ together with a natural transformation $$\gamma:F\circ T\Rightarrow T'\circ F$$ such that $\gamma\circ(1\star\eta)=\eta'\star1$ and $(\mu'\star1)\circ(1\star\gamma)\circ(\gamma\star1)=\gamma\circ(1\star\mu)$, so anything about lax morphisms of monads in this sense is welcome too (particularly if it discusses the relationship to the above notion of morphisms of adjunctions).

Comment: Note that if you identify adjunctions in a 2-category with 2-functors whose domain is the "walking adjunction", then your notion of morphism should be just a colax natural transformation between such 2-functors.

Comment: @MikeShulman That view is fascinating to me, but I asked specifically for writings at the $1$-categorical level because I'm still more comfortable there despite being able to parse higher categorical parlance. When I have some more time to really learn higher category theory I'd love to read points of view expanding on the one you mention.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find very much written about morphisms of adjunctions at a 1-categorical level, since "morally" an adjunction is a 2-categorical concept.

Comment: @MikeShulman After playing with these ideas some more I definitely agree, $2$-categories are lurking in the background waiting to appropriately arrange everything into nice coherent lemmas/theorems. If there is any $2$-categorical writing about this stuff you're aware of I'd be interested in reading it.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing comes to mind that specifically addresses this notion of morphism.